# Does event handler binding location affect performance?

Tags: javascript, performance

Which is best from a performance standpoint: place bindings outside an event handler so they are not declared each time it is called or define them as part of the event handler in order to avert the need to look the bindings up in the surrounding scope. Also, is this kind of thing worth worrying about?

```js
function Accordion(accordion) {
  const handles = accordion.querySelectorAll(SELECTOR_HANDLE);
  const lastHandleIndex = handles.length - 1;
  const navigationKeys = ["ArrowUp", "ArrowDown", "Home", "End"];
  let targetHandleIndex = 0;
  ...
  function navigateUsingKeyboard(event) {
    const currentHandleIndex = handles.indexOf(event.currentTarget);
    ...
  }
  ...
  handles.forEach((handle) => {
    ...
    handle.addEventListener("keydown", navigateUsingKeyboard);
  });
}
```

OR

```js
function Accordion(accordion) {
  const handles = accordion.querySelectorAll(SELECTOR_HANDLE);
  ...
  function navigateUsingKeyboard(event) {
    const currentHandleIndex = handles.indexOf(event.currentTarget);
    const lastHandleIndex = handles.length - 1;
    const navigationKeys = ["ArrowUp", "ArrowDown", "Home", "End"];
    let targetHandleIndex = 0;
    ...
  }
  ...
  handles.forEach((handle) => {
    ...
    handle.addEventListener("keydown", navigateUsingKeyboard);
  });
}
```

Comment: "is this kind of thing worth worrying about?" no.